# Is it possible to export a VSCode color theme to PhpStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm

I recently needed to move from VSCode to PhpStorm IDE, and I would like to know if there is a way to export my color theme too. [Here](https://github.com/endormi/vscode-2077-theme) is the theme I use in VSCode.

Because the theme is a JSON file, I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done; in PhpStorm, themes are not JSON files but java LAFs.
However, we have plenty of themes available in the repository, see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?headline=164-theme&products=phpstorm&tags=Theme., please check [Cyberpunk Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15563-cyberpunk-theme) or [CyberpunkUI Color Scheme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15775-cyberpunkui-color-scheme), for example.

If none of them looks good for you, you can try developing your own one. [Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes.html) are the guidelines for creating a custom theme plugin/customizing a theme